# What was the relationship between R' Azriel Hildesheimer and R' Samson Raphael Hirsch and how do they differ?

Tags: rabbis, samson-raphael-hirsch, german

They were contemporaries and similar in many ways.

Comment: I suppose both were rabbis, but their names differed. Or would you like to know something else in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Yisrael and welcome to Mi Yodeya.

Both Rabbis embraced the notion of 'Torah Im Derech Eretz' and cultivated what has since been coined '[Neo-Orthodoxy](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Neo-Orthodoxy)'. They also both embarked on a policy of *Austritt* or 'Withdrawal' leading separatist communities (Rabbi Hirsch's *Israelitische Religiongesellschaft* (IRG) congregation in Frankfurt and Rabbi Hildersheimer - the Adass Jisroel community in Berlin) in a bid to fight against the emerging Reform movement and non-observant element in the community.

However, it is this area of separatism where they differed. There is a very astute critical analysis [here](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol22Kashkin.pdf) where the author Yisrael Kashkin notes that Rabbi Hirsch's secession was far more comprehensive whereas Rabbi Hildersheimer was willing to work to a degree with the non-observant members of the community.

Indeed this view is supported in a biographical account of Rabbi Hildersheimer [here](https://www.haaretz.com/jewish/.premium-this-day-rabbi-who-urged-orthodox-to-join-the-world-1.5363977) where it states:

> *What can be said is that Hirsch was the more conservative of the two: He was more of a segregationist, who had no interest in cooperation with his ideological opponents; more of an instrumentalist with regard to secular studies; and by no means sympathetic to the emerging nationalist strain of Zionism.*